# Formatting all empty rows using looping

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to find out how to loop the following VBA Macro in Excel. I need to find all the empty rows and format them (not delete or hide them as in other suggestions) as you can see in the existing code below:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(, 0).Resize(1, 14).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

I want to loop this until all empty rows have been formatted.

Comment: You want to loop the entire sheet? That will take a lot of time. What's wrong with conditional formatting and not using VBA?

Comment: This data will be used by users who are not familiar with Excel. All they will have to do is export from web portal, keyboard shortcut and print. This will never be a huge spreadsheet.

Comment: So I could find a way to apply conditional formatting to all rows so if they are empty, they will be formatted accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Application.CountA(Range("A" & i & ":N" & i).EntireRow) = 0 Then
        With Range("A" & i & ":N" & i).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Although I agree that your best solution is using conditional formatting :)

Comment: This worked and did it very fast. The reason I need a VBA to do this, is because the employees in production are not familiar with Excel. All they need to do is click on export button, keyboard shortcut and then print. It is their daily job list. One for production and the other sheet for shipping. This script worked just fine and these two sheets will never be too large.

Comment: @James Keep in mind, you will have to rerun the macro every time you make a change in the worksheet. You will also will have to come up with a solution to reverse any changes made by this macro in the event that the changes no longer apply.

Comment: Yes, once this macro runs, it is done and the next day, they will do it all over again on a new set of data. I do see what you are saying, but in this scenario this will do just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the cells can later be edited and the formatting needs to be removed for no-longer-empty rows, then your one-time initial formatting isn't going to cut it. Best setup your generated worksheet (assuming you're generating that worksheet) with a conditional format.

You do that by creating `FormatCondition` objects, using the `FormatConditions` collection of your target `Range`:

```
Public Sub HighlightEmptyRows()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C10") 'change as needed
    With target.FormatConditions
        Dim condition As FormatCondition
        Set condition = .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTA($A1:$C1)=0")
        With condition
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If no VBA code is generating that worksheet, then [don't write VBA code for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343813/1188513)

Comment: Yes, there is VBA Macro that is already at play and that is why I just wanted to tag this on to have it done and easy for those employees who do not know Excel. I agree with your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

An extremely efficient, non-VBA solution would be to use conditional formatting and not use VBA at all.

1. Select the ENTIRE worksheet by clicking the corner between the Columns and row headers
2. Open Conditional Formatting Menu
3. Click on "New Rule"
4. Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
5. Enter the following formula in the box: `=COUNTBLANK(1:1)=16384`
6. Select your desired formatting

The reason this works is because Excel is *counting* the number of blank cells in each row. Depending on the version of Excel being used, we already know there are **16384** columns in a row. So, if `=countblank()` returns a value other than your number, then it knows at least one cell has data in it.